# c# read a fields value from a row in a datagridview looping

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, foreach

Ok so i have a lil function that will get a value from a field in each row of a datagridview..........
then look at what the value is and count an according increment.

heres the code so far:

```
    private void countParetoQty(int top, int tmid, int bmid, int bot )
    {
        //bunch of Ifs to count a record thats certain pareto

        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1)
        {
            if(//current row @ pareto <=50)
            {
                //top 50
                top++;
            }
            else 
                if()
                {
                    //50-100
                    tmid++;
                }
                else
                    if()
                    {
                        //100-200
                        bmid++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //its over 200!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                        bot++;
                    }
        }
```

as you can see i need to check the fields value "Pareto" on each row and cycle through afew If statements to increment the correct int.
I need to know how i get the value im looking for an cycle through.
Im thinking along the lines of foreach loop then conditioning by the current rows column.value?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a cell value as following:

```
row.Cells["FiledName"].Value
```

or by index

```
row.Cells[0].Value
```

Comment: i had a funny feeling about that, so the logic im using and methodology is right? or is there a better way?

Comment: yes cast it to int or pars value to int using int.parse(Row.Cells["Pareto"].Value.toString())

Comment: yeh i use a cast seem to work great! many thanks, knew it was something simple

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the Pareto Column like this:

```
  int testValue = Row.Cells["Pareto"].Value;
```

Given that you have the row already, and that pareto is an integer.

I might also use a switch instead of nested ifs.

Comment: idd, im using (int) row.cells["Pareto"].value to cast the object to an int. yeh ill probably convert to a switch thinking about it.